# lexical and preprocessor issue in testing kit.h file? Xcode 4 testing files

Tags: xcode, file, project, preprocessor, lexical

I'm 14 and kind of new to Xcode 4.6, so I really don't know much about it. When I was working on my app, I got an error out of nowhere saying lexical and preprocessor issue in my .h test files. I didn't type anything on that file and every time  I start over, it pops up. It also says my importing files aren't found? I didn't import anything except for the project already. How do I fix it?

Comment: Post the file's code so that we can see what's wrong.

Comment: [IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/wqq82x.png[/IMG] @ChrisLoonam

Comment: Is SenTestingKit.framework added as a framework?